# i want to trigger the script automatically, without havin to click out of the input neither pressing enter

Tags: complex-event-processing

```
      

   <!-- Adicionando Javascript -->
    <script>
    
    function limpa_formulário_cep() {
            //Limpa valores do formulário de cep.
            document.getElementById('rua').value=("");
            document.getElementById('bairro').value=("");
            document.getElementById('cidade').value=("");
            document.getElementById('uf').value=("");
            document.getElementById('ibge').value=("");
    }

    function meu_callback(conteudo) {
        if (!("erro" in conteudo)) {
            //Atualiza os campos com os valores.
            document.getElementById('rua').value=(conteudo.logradouro);
            document.getElementById('bairro').value=(conteudo.bairro);
            document.getElementById('cidade').value=(conteudo.localidade);
            document.getElementById('uf').value=(conteudo.uf);
            document.getElementById('ibge').value=(conteudo.ibge);
        } //end if.
        else {
            //CEP não Encontrado.
            limpa_formulário_cep();
            alert("CEP não encontrado.");
        }
    }
        
    function pesquisacep(valor) {

        //Nova variável "cep" somente com dígitos.
        var cep = valor.replace(/\D/g, '');

        //Verifica se campo cep possui valor informado.
        if (cep != "") {

            //Expressão regular para validar o CEP.
            var validacep = /^[0-9]{8}$/;

            //Valida o formato do CEP.
            if(validacep.test(cep)) {

                //Preenche os campos com "..." enquanto consulta 
              webservice.
                document.getElementById('rua').value="...";
                document.getElementById('bairro').value="...";
                document.getElementById('cidade').value="...";
                document.getElementById('uf').value="...";
                document.getElementById('ibge').value="...";

                //Cria um elemento javascript.
                var script = document.createElement('script');

                //Sincroniza com o callback.
                script.src = 'https://viacep.com.br/ws/'+ cep + '/json/? 
             callback=meu_callback';

                //Insere script no documento e carrega o conteúdo.
                document.body.appendChild(script);

            } //end if.
            else {
                //cep é inválido.
                limpa_formulário_cep();
                alert("Formato de CEP inválido.");
            }
        } //end if.
        else {
            //cep sem valor, limpa formulário.
            limpa_formulário_cep();
        }
    };

    </script>

                     
                <html>
    <head>
    <title>ViaCEP Webservice</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

 
    </head>

    <body>
    <!-- Inicio do formulario -->
      <form method="get" action=".">
        <label>Cep:
        <input name="cep" type="text" id="cep" value="" size="10" maxlength="9"
               onblur="pesquisacep(this.value);" /></label><br />
        <label>Rua:
        <input name="rua" type="text" id="rua" size="60" /></label><br />
        <label>Bairro:
        <input name="bairro" type="text" id="bairro" size="40" /></label><br />
        <label>Cidade:
        <input name="cidade" type="text" id="cidade" size="40" /></label> 
         <br />
        <label>Estado:
        <input name="uf" type="text" id="uf" size="2" /></label><br />
        <label>IBGE:
        <input name="ibge" type="text" id="ibge" size="8" /></label><br />
      </form>
```

Guys this script runs fine, as you can see here : https://codepen.io/RafaMenegassi/pen/GRrMBLm the thing is when i type for example 00000-000 this numbers of numbers i want to trigger the script automatically, without havin to click out of the input neither pressing enter.
https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/javascript/

Comment: the code can be found here https://viacep.com.br/exemplo/javascript/

Comment: https://codepen.io/RafaMenegassi/pen/GRrMBLm

Comment: Try using <body onload=“function()”>

Comment: How do i do that? can you show me?

Comment: I’ve added an answer below

Answer (score 0):

At the top of your html page, do this:

`<body onload=“limpa_formulário_cep()”> ... ... (rest of your html and JavaScript code)`

When the page loads, this function SHOULD run

Comment: thank you for trying but didnt work....i still had to click out or press enter https://codepen.io/RafaMenegassi/pen/GRrMBLm

Comment: im looking for something like this https://codepen.io/EuclidesMarques/pen/vmJdNm